# Looking for a fantasy book I started reading but never finished

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I don't remember much about it I just remember that it started with the place where a kid lived is destroyed.

The main detail I remember is that the portal to the other land is an imperfect street intersection.

If I remember correctly I believe it gets destroyed by an evil guy looking for someone. I also think the main character had a mythical creature that always followed him around but don't remember what the creature was. It might've been a Trailer Park and I think there was a tree that was very important to the story.

Comment: Welcome! I hope you find it :) It's okay not to remember too many details, I guess that's why you're here, but this is rather little to go on, the more you can give us, anything really, the better. When did you read it, for example? Can you guess what the intended audience was? Even the front cover? On the, you get out what you put in theme, this could also do with some language tidying up. E.g.: "it started with the place where a kid lived is destroyed". By this do you mean that it starts with the place being destroyed, we see it get destroyed, or the fact that it is/has been destroyed?

Comment: This sounds like a small part of *The Subtle Knife* by Philip Pullman but we need a lot more detail to give a sensible answer.

Comment: sounds like Harry Potter